# How can I get in python the size of received packet in bytes ?

Tags: python, packet

I created socket AF_PACKET and receive all packages:

```
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))
while True:
    raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65536)
    print(' SIZE = {}'.format(len(raw_data)))
```

It prints mainly 90 and 60, but the size of ethernet frame is 1500 bytes. 
What is the correct function to get the size in bytes of these packets ?

Comment: It's `len`. That's the way.

Comment: hey, thanks for answer. But why does it print 60 and 90 when it should print 1500 ?

Comment: I can't answer that, only that whatever assumptions you are making to that say you should be receiving 1500 bytes are not correct. For me, this is getting deep into black box territory.

Comment: i am pretty sure they are called packets for a reason. small and digestible.

Answer (score 0):

The `bytes` object is exactly what it says. Getting the length of a bytes object is getting it's size, and a bytes object is what the socket returns. You've got it right the whole way.

Comment: hmm it doesn't? i've been working with a normal `recv` and it's all fine. what's different about `recvfrom`?